# I don’t understand the two ISOMORPHISM embedding definitions of planar graph in plantri software

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

The *plantri* (see [http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/plantri/](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ebdm/plantri/)) is a program that generates certain types of graphs that are
**imbedded on the sphere**. Exactly one member of each isomorphism class is output.

Recently I am using the  plantri to obtain the  graph data of the *non-isomorphic* 3-connected planar quadrangulations with 12 vertices.  The isomorphism here refers to the abstract graph isomorphism.

- An *isomorphism* of graphs $G$ and $H$is a bijection
  between the vertex sets of $G$ and $H$. ${\displaystyle f\colon
   V(G)\to V(H)}$ such that any two vertices $u$ and $v$ of $G$ are
  adjacent in G if and only if ${\displaystyle f(u)}$ and
  ${\displaystyle f(v)}$ are adjacent in $H$. This kind of bijection is
  commonly described as "edge-preserving bijection".
- If an isomorphism exists between two graphs, then the graphs are called *isomorphic* and denoted as ${\displaystyle G\simeq H}$.

But I can see from the help document of this plantri that the isomorphism it defines seems to be different.

So I'm worried whether it's giving me all   non-isomorphic 3-connected planar quadrangulations with $n$ vertices.

> In defining "*isomorphism*" for two imbedded graphs, we have the
> choice of   whether or not to automatically regard a graph and its
> *mirror image* as   isomorphic.  plantri knows both definitions:
>
> Let $G$ and $H$ be two connected imbedded graphs with the same numbers
> of   vertices and the same number of edges.
>
> An **ORIENTATION-PRESERVING (O-P) ISOMORPHISM** from $G$ to $H$ is a
> bijection $f_v$   from $V(G)$ to $V(H)$, and a bijection fe from
> $E(G)$ to  $E(H)$, such that
>
> - (1) If $e = \{v_1,v_2\}$ is in $E(G)$, then $f_e(e) = \{f_v(v_1),f_v(v_2)\}$ and $f_e(e)$ is in $E(H)$.
> - (2) If $(e_1,e_2,...,e_k)$ is the set of edges incident with a vertex $v$ of $G$,
>   in clockwise order, then $(f_e(e_1),f_e(e_2),...,f_e(e_k))$ is the set of
>   edges incident with the vertex $f_v(v)$ of G, in *clockwise order*.
>
> An **ORIENTATION-REVERSING (O-R) ISOMORPHISM** from $G$ to $H$ is a
> bijection $f_v$   from $V(G)$ to $V(H)$, and a bijection $f_e$ from
> $E(G)$ to $E(H)$, such that
>
> - (1) If $e = \{v_1,v_2\}$ is in $E(G)$, then $f_e(e) = \{f_v(v_1),f_v(v_2)\}$ and $f_e(e)$ is in $E(H)$.
> - (2) If $(e_1,e_2,...,e_k)$ is the set of edges incident with a vertex $v$ of $G$,
>   in clockwise order, then $(f_e(e_1),f_e(e_2),...,f_e(e_k))$ is the set of
>   edges incident with the vertex $f_v(v)$ of G, in *anti-clockwise order*.

The MIRROR IMAGE of an imbedded graph is obtained by reversing all the
cyclic orders.  That corresponds to turning the sphere inside out.

[image]
The  mirror image of the above graph is

[image]
[image]

An *ISOMORPHISM* from $G$ to $H$ is either an O-P isomorphism or an O-R
isomorphism.  Isomorphism and O-P isomorphism (but not O-R isomorphism)
are equivalence relations, so we can speak of ISOMORPHISM CLASSES and
O-P ISOMORPHISM CLASSES.

So I saw data of  numbers of 3-connected planar quadrangulations  like this:

[image]

More details see  this web [http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/plantri/plantri-guide.txt](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ebdm/plantri/plantri-guide.txt)

**My questions are the following:**

- 1. Are the  graphs  with $n$ vertices obtained by  *ISOMORPHISM*  definition from plantri  mutual  abstract non-isomorphism?
- 2. If the graph is 3-connected, there are exactly two embeddings (which are equivalent if we allow orientation-reversing flips). This is a celebrated theorem of H. Whitney. I feel that the O-P non-isomorphic graph class should be twice the  number of all non-ISOMORPHISM class. But we don’t think so from the data. When $n=8$, the number of nonisomorphic  planar quadrangulations and O-P non-isomorphic  planar quadrangulations  are all equal to 1.  And when $n=14$, the number of nonisomorphic  planar quadrangulations are $11$, however the number of  O-P non-isomorphic  planar quadrangulations are $15$. $15 \ne 2\times 11$.

I'll use the unique 3-connected planar quadrangulation with 8 vertices as an example.

[image: the only planar quadrangulation with 8 vertices]

[image]

The right is the mirror image of the left.  They don't seem to be op isomorphic. So as you can see in the picture below 1 should be corrected to 2, right?

[image]

I feel that there is a problem with my understanding of graph embedded isomorphism from plantri software.

Comment: Isn't $1 \mapsto 2$, $2 \mapsto 1$, $3 \mapsto 4$, $4 \mapsto 3$, $8 \mapsto 7$, $7 \mapsto 8$, $5 \mapsto 6$, $6 \mapsto 5$ an orientation-preserving isomorphism of the graph labelled as on the left with its mirror image labelled as on the right?

Comment: You are right. I previously ignored such mappings to ensure that they are op isomorphism, and I have been thinking that the identity mapping is not satisfied.

Comment: Whitney's Theorem does not say that there are two **different** embeddings. An embedding can be the same as its mirror image, so the number of OP-isomorphism classes can be less than twice the number of isomorphism classes.

Comment: Also for 3-connected graphs plantri's default isomorphism is equivalent to abstract isomorphism.  That isn't true if the connectivity is less than 3.

Comment: @  Brendan McKay Thanks, sir. I feel that the isomorphism (or equivalent) of   embedding of graph defined by Whitney is also different from your plantri.  I read in the book that he defined it this way. ( Nishizeki T, Chiba N. Planar graphs: Theory and algorithms[M]. Elsevier, 1988.) Two embemddings are  isomorphism (or equivalent) when the boundary of a face in one embedding always coreesponds to the boundary of a face in the other. It really doesn't say that an embedding  can be the same as its mirror image based on  OP-isomorphism, as you say.